# For loop powershell multithreading

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I have a powershell script that runs through an dynamic array with a for loop.
This goes rather slow when the array contains a lot of values.
It only executes the code with a single core.

How is it possible to multithread this for loop? In this for loop multiple arrays are created. The indexes of these arrays should stay the same.

For example index 2 of array1 should correspond with index 2 of array2.

Is this possible?

There are 4 arrays returned out of this for loop: 
$GroupMemberArray, $Global:ASISArray, $Global:TOBEFArray, $DepTeamArray

There are 8 variables that are being used in this for loop.

Arrays:$TableFullPath, $SplitUp, $SplitDown,$TablePermissionType, $Tablerights, $TableDistName

String:$StrLevelUp

Integer:$IntLevelInitial

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $TableFullPath.count; $i++)
{
#Custom code
}
```

Comment: Check [here](http://www.get-blog.com/?p=189), you can use this technique to do parallel jobs of custom code.

Comment: Your code snippet is a bit long, don't you think?

Comment: You can take a look at `Get-Help about_Foreach-Parallel` and `Get-Help about_Parallel`, but both those methods require the use of [Workflows](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj574157), which are fairly complex.